It takes more time on flink v1.16.3 than flink v1.7.1 when stopping the standalone cluster
I have a standalone session cluster which runs three jobs(2 master nodes, 50 slave or worker nodes), now that when it is flink v1.7, it takes around several seconds(less than 1 minute) to stop the cluster.
but, when I switch this to flink v1.16, it takes around several minutes to stop the cluster(the stop-cluster.sh even complains about 10 seconds  timeout on killing some taskmanagers)
Both two version use rocksdb as statebackend, aligned checkpoint(state size has no significant difference)
I don't know how to check this (no helpful or warn log found)
I used jemalloc mem allocator
Any help would be much appreciated

i'd like to know is there any config which could fix this ? btw, i didn't use k8s
